# VIM spelling function

Tags: vim

I wan't to have a function that turns spell check on then go's to the next misspelled word and replaces with the first suggestion heres what I've got so far:

```
function! Spell_new_word()
  set spell=true
  exe ']s'
  exe '1z='
  set spell=false
endfunction
```

but it only seems to set spelling to true and doesn't do anything.... what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I've tired changing exe to normal, but still no luck:

```
function! Spell_new_word()
  set spell!
  normal ']s'
  normal '1z='
  set spell!
endfunction
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've tired this and it still doesn't work:

```
function! Spell_new_word()
  set spell
  normal ]s
  normal 1z=
  set nospell
endfunction
```

But I don't think that is the problem I think thats its not binding to `,d`:

```
let mapleader = ","
namp ,d Spell_next_word()
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest [this function](https://github.com/sergioro9/vim-spell) for quick spell checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nnoremap ,d :call Spell_next_word()^M
```

things to note:

1. choose mode (normal mode, no remapping)
2. include `:` to enter command mode
3. `call` the function
4. Execute it! The `^M` is *normally* entered with <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on linux, or <kbd>C-Q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows

Additionally, perhaps include

```
inoremap ,d ^O:call Spell_next_word()^M
```

(again typeing the `^O` as <kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> or <kbd>C-Q</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd>)

Comment: Rather than having control characters in your config for something like this, you can replace `^M` with `<CR>` (case insensitive).

Comment: @Randy: good to know! Does that extrapolate to all control characters? E.q. `g<C-u>` instead of `g^U`

Comment: if I understand you correctly, yes.  For instance, you could have `nmap t <C-t>` as a mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Change `exe` to `normal`. `exe` is for executing command line commands.

Comment: still nothing, and the spelling checker seems to be still on after the command is run

Answer (score 2):

In addition to implementing Austin's answer (see my comment underneath), you need to learn how to toggle vim's settings on and off.  This is explained in the various entries under [`:help :set`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%3aset).  Specifically, you should use `set spell` to enable spelling and `set nospell` to disable it.

There are some other configurations which may need to be done to get spelling correction working, like setting `'spelllang'`.  Have a read through [`:help spell.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html#spell.txt) for the details.

Comment: I have spell lang set... check my updated answer... I can't seem to map ,d to the function

Comment: Ahh.  You have to make the mapping `call SpellNewWord()`.  Try just doing `:call SpellNewWord()` from command mode.

Comment: it works, thanks! do you know how I could get it mapped to ,d?